# In Which File SolrConfig.xml file path is configured?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting 
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file

> **C:\nemoCode\sceneric-hybris\hybris\config\solr\embedded\solrconfig.xml**

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.550 |     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.550 |     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.550 |     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:251)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.550 |     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:243)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.550 |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 |     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.551 | Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'C:\nemoCode\sceneric-hybris\hybris\config\solr\embedded\conf'
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.552 |     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:342)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.552 |     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:288)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.552 |     at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.552 |     at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.553 |     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:139)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.553 |     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:527)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/05/23 11:54:01.553 |     ... 9 more
```

But I dont have that path in my c drive. Where it is configured that it should serach from that perticular file path???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the path is configured inside your solr.xml , you will find it inside **${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/solr/embedded/solr.xml**

The solr.xml file specifies configuration options for each Solr core, including configuration options for multiple cores. The file also contains mappings for request URLs, and indicates which cores to load when the server starts.

**so check the instanceDir and dataDir of one of your cores**

An example of core inside solr.xml

```
 <core name="master_apparel-de_Product"
 instanceDir="A:\source\hybris.5.2.0\hybris\config/solr/embedded"
 dataDir="A:\source\hybris.5.2.0\hybris\data\solrfacetsearch\MASTER\apparel-de_Product_1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a usual location for solrconfig.xml. Usually the location is:
**[solr.home]/[corename]/conf/solrconfig.xml**

It is possible to deviate from that by changing **config** property in the **core.properties** files that is just in the **[corename]** directory. That location can be relative which is what may be causing you some issues.